# How can I share object level logic across Entity Framework queries?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am looking to share some very simple logic across multiple queries in Entity Framework. Say I have the following models

```
public class User
{
    // user properties
    public ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole : IDateRestricted
{
    public RoleType Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}

public interface IDateRestricted
{
    DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

If I was using normal LINQ I could create a simple extension method that would allow me to determine if the role was currently active.

```
public static class DateRestrictedExtensions
{
    public static Boolean IsActive(this IDateRestricted entity)
    {
        return entity.StartDate <= DateTime.Now && (entity.EndDate == null || entity.EndDate > DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

and I could use it like so.

```
var admins = users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(role => role.Type == RoleType.Admin && role.IsActive()));
```

With entity framework this fails with the dreaded:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `Boolean IsActive(Domain.Interfaces.IDateRestricted)` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Is there a way that I can share this logic and have LINQ to Entities support it when querying?

Comment: You will need to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) or roll your own equivalent.

Comment: You could also create extensions that return `Expression<Func>` types but you would need to pass them as the whole parameter of the e.g. `Any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Expression<Func<IDateRestricted, bool>>` instead of `Func<IDateRestricted, bool>` - presented exception's description exactly points to it:

```
public static class DateRestrictedExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<IDateRestricted, bool>> IsActive()
    {
        return entity => entity.StartDate <= DateTime.Now 
                         && (entity.EndDate == null || entity.EndDate > DateTime.Now);
    }
}

var admins = users.Where(x => x.Roles.AsQueryable().Where(role.Type == RoleType.Admin)
                                   .Any(DateRestrictedExtensions.IsActive()));
```

Comment: Thought about this but the `.Any()` method does not accept an expression it would seem

Comment: Adding `.AsQueryable()` to the roles collection allows it to work.  Also you must include the static class name in the method call.  If you update the answer with these I will accept it.

Comment: @AaronRoberts, can you explain, why it is not working without `.AsQueryable()`. What problem did you face?

Comment: there is no error because it doesn’t build. The LINQ extension methods on an ICollection don’t accept expression functions as a parameter.

Comment: @AaronRoberts, yes, indeed, fixed.